# Taking screenshots on Windows, OSX-style

Tags: windows, macos

At work I can take screenshots of my entire screen with command+shift+3, or of a specific area with command+shift+4. Both commands output a .png file and drop it on the desktop without any further action needed from me.

On the other hand, with Windows, I've got to hit the printscreen button, open paint, paste the screenshot in, crop it (if needed), and save it to the desktop (or any other folder).

Is there any way to make a shortcut in Windows 7 that works like the one in OSX -without- having to download external programs like TinyGrab or Jing?

Comment: Lets start with the basics.  What version of Windows?  There is the "Snipping Tool" that exists in Windows 7 or later but other then that what you describe requires a third-party tool.

Comment: Windows 7. Forgot to add that to the question. My bad.

Comment: ATRamhound, no,  the "snipping tool"  (while useful) does not that the facility he describes of automatically saving to a filename.

Comment: @barlop - I understand the snipping tool wasn't exactly what he wanted, but besides that and print screen which he doesn't want to use, there are no other tools built into Windows hence my comment about third-party tools.  I should have just voted to close this question instead of commenting to avoid pretty useless comment from you.

Comment: ATRamhoudn your comment about the snipping tool was very misleading. He asked for what he asked for and if you're going to suggest something that you know doesn't do what he asked then you should say it doesn't do what he asked, otherwise the suggestion is that it does what he asked. I actually was 99% sure that snipping tool didn't do what he asked / that your suggestion didn't work, but after your comment I wasted my time checking just to make sure. Your comment was misleading. If you know your suggestion doesn't do what he wanted then say so. And he is obviously aware of 3rd party tools.

Comment: AtRamhound If the answer to a question is(as u say-not possible) i.e. "no it is not possible, no past or current windows version supports that" then that's a pretty definite answer. I don't see why you think a question whose answer would be that, would "merit" closing the question. Furthermore, if the windows version makes no difference (I think it doesn't make a difference - unless some windows versions have a feature allowing it that others don't), then it's better not to be explicit about a windows version unnecessarily. Though you insist on getting specific about one single windows version

Comment: Corn, perhaps it's possible.. making an icon shortcut then a keyboard shortcut to that icon shortcut, and the shortcut could run a Vbscript or Powershell might be able to do it such that clicking a shortcut makes a screenshot in a file. You might want to make a new question tagged vbscript or powershell asking how to make a script that saves a screenshot to a file. Then make an icon shortcut to it, right click go to properties, to make a keyboard shortcut to it and see if it works.

Comment: @barlop - The tool I suggest for instance does not exist in Windows XP.  Its often the case tools will be added to Windows sort of like `Windows Media Player` in later versions of Windows or removed in certain regional versions of Windows like in the case of WMP.  If I want to know what version of Windows they are using specifically I shouldn't have to explain the reason.  A detailed question is never a bad thing and knowing the specific version of an operating system and being able to research what tools exist on it can only help the user.

Comment: AT Ramhound this convo can be continued in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19418860#19418860

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's impossible.
Yes there's the snipping tool, a great one, but you have to open it...

IF you're a Dropbox user, with the tool launched, it may store .png files to your cloud after a PrntSreen.
(Not a third-party for me as Dropbox is always open)

Comment: -1 he said save to a file, so the 'snipping tool' doesn't apply. And he said no external programs so dropbox if it even does what you describe, doesn't apply.